# C++: Reverse this hash?

Tags: c++, encryption, hash

I have been using this to hash my passwords but I have a feeling it isn't very secure. I've been googling around to see if someone has decrypted a string using this. This is the encryption algorithm, I'm not sure how to go about reversing the math to decrypt hashes instead. Any help would be welcomed. This is the encrypter in C++.

EDIT: I do plan on switching to a more secure method of hashing passwords, however in order to do this I need to reverse the math to convert it to plain text before I convert to the new hashed SHA256 string. People don't seem to understand me here, I understand this is insecure, this is just showing the algorithm in c++. It is actually for a different language. I am limited on what I can do and how I do it in that language.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    char hasher[256];
    cout<< "Input a string!"<<endl;
    cin>> hasher;
    cout << endl;


for(int x=0; x < strlen(hasher); x++)
  {
      hasher[x] += (3^x) * (x % 15);
      if(hasher[x] > (255))
      {
          hasher[x] -= 256;
      }
  }

  cout << hasher << endl;
  system("pause");
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Its an encrypted string. Sorry.

Comment: Does your `char` type have more than 8 bits? Otherwise, `hasher[x] > (255)` will never be true.

Comment: I'm not sure. All char types are 8 bits correct?

Comment: It isn't a hash by at least two parameters (most likely reversible && produces result of different size for inputs of different sizes). Why do you want to use so weak function instead of well known and tested SHA or bcrypt?

Comment: Yes they are. Also, anyone that sees your code (which is now public) can get the original string back.

Comment: By the way, you may have char 0 in your encrypted string (for example every 15th char), causing cout and other functions to consider only a part of it.

Comment: I don't even see what your question is... but anyway you should definitely not be inventing or implementing your own crypto functions. You can have reliable crypto in any incarnation you want already. Use them.

Comment: If you want someone to write code to reverse the hash for you, you should probably post this on ODesk.

Comment: *Removed code for security.* Just try to click the **edited** link below the answer. @amal

Comment: All the answers don't make sense anymore, when there is no code. I rolled back your last edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a number to the character based upon position. Just subtract that number 3^x etc

Comment: Thanks. This is really insecure. I figured it wouldn't be too hard to do this but I wasn't sure how to reverse the math.

Answer (score 2):

You modify every char, [only based on its relative position in the string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher).  This is an **extremely weak** way to proceed. It won't resist a [plain text attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) (if you know two passwords, and its encoding):

```
password  ->  pcusôìÉÇ
abaaa     ->  adca}
```

So the attacker will immediately notice that the first and fourth char remain unchanged, and the second and third shifts by 2 letters. On an average 8 letters password, half of it would be broken.  And unfortunately many passwords might be guessed from the first four letters !

In fact it will be easy in this way to find out the other shifts 0,2,2,0,28, 30,30,28,88,80,90,.... (less  impressive than your formula, isn't it ?).

You put **your users really at risk** here.  Better, go to a standard hash function [such as sha512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) and store only the hash in the database. This means that it's not possible to find back the password (missing information).  But you can verify if the password the user typed is correct by calculating the hash of its input and compare it to the hash in the database (see [*"article Safely storing user passwords"*](http://www.darkreading.com/safely-storing-user-passwords-hashing-vs-encrypting/a/d-id/1269374)).

Comment: I do plan on switching to a more secure method of hashing passwords, however in order to do this I need to reverse the math to convert it to plain text before I convert to the new hashed SHA256 string. People don't seem to understand me here, I understand this is insecure, this is just showing the algorithm in c++. It is actually for a different language. I am limited on what I can do and how I do it in that language.

Comment: @ArtjomB. you're correct. To have a 0 with an ascii password would require an "L" as 13th letter in the password.  I edidted my answer.